# Why is the request handler called continuously (like every second) in node?

Tags: node.js, request

I've got this (complete code – well, sort of):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const Router = require('./router');
const Utils = require('./utils');
const utils = new Utils();
const views = require('./views');

let hostname,
    server,
    router = new Router();

    const port = ( process.argv.length > 2 ) ? parseInt(process.argv[process.argv.length - 1]) : 3000;

function install ( config ) {
    let install_processes = [
        installControllers( config ),
        installModels( config ),
        views( config )
    ];

    return Promise.all( install_processes );
}

function installControllers ( config ) {
// To keep example compact, this return a Promise
}

function installModels ( config ) {
// To keep example compact, this return a Promise
}

function handleRequest ( req, res ) {
    let r = global.routes.find( ( obj ) => obj.route === req.url );

    if ( r ) {
        let template = global.routes.views.layout,
        output = template( req.body );
        r.action();

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.end( output );
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end("404: page not found, " + req.url);
    }
}

var fw = (function ( ƒ ) {
    ƒ.init = function Init ( config ) {
        config = config;

        hostname = config.hostname ? config.hostname : '127.0.0.1';

        install( config )
        .then(function () {
            ƒ.startServer();
        })
        .catch(function ( err ) {
console.error("Error", err);
        })
    }

    ƒ.startServer = function () {
        server = http.createServer( handleRequest ).listen(port, hostname, () => {
            console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
        });
    }

    return ƒ;
}( fw || {} ));

module.exports = fw;
```

*Please note, that variables and handlers are set elsewhere.*

Everything works fine. But why is the `handleRequest` handler called every second (without any incoming requests. And it's actually called TWICE within that second)? If I add a console.log it gets output every second or so.

I would expect it to be called ONLY when actual requests are made to the server. Is this some sort of timeout handler that runs in the background or the like?

Comment: *this some sort of timeout handler that runs in the background or the like* - no, there isn't, unless you created it yourself. This totally depends on your code which you didn't provide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a requirement for questions on SO. Other users should be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: This is the 'complete' code (some things removed to keep it compact(!)):
Argh, comeon ... can't paste that amount of code here ... So, now I have to 'Answer my own question'?

Comment: You removed relevant parts of code when keeping things compact. Sometimes you cannot know what to remove without knowing the answer, this is the case. You don't have to post an answer if you don't intend to answer. Please, edit the question and paste all relevant code there instead.

Comment: The code you posted isn't MCVE. It can be as minimal as needed but should replicate the problem. You won't be able to do this. Please, try it from the scratch yourself. It doesn't contain anything that would obviously cause the problem you have. I can only suppose that there are some recursive requests because routing was set up incorrectly like redirects, or page resources weren't found and 404 were handled incorrectly. Any way, only you can debug it.

Comment: You should log `req.url`. It's possible that the second request is the browser attempting to access the server's [`favicon.ico`](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/web-security-appliance/117995-qna-wsa-00.html)

Comment: Christ all freakin' ... I usually develop using a middle of the road browser (Firefox) ... to catch more bugs. At some point I had opened Chrome to use the debugger, and forgot all about it. THAT was the bugger continuously sending requests ... sigh! Yes, web dev IS hard.

Answer (score 0):

Why is handle triggered twice when starting the server, that is?

Try adding this to a file (wtf.js) and run: `node wtf 9000`;

```

```
const http = require('http');

function handle ( req, res ) {
    console.log("Handling request");
}

var fw = (function () {
    http.createServer( handle ).listen(9000, '127.0.0.1',  () => {
        console.log("Server running");
    });
}());

module.exports = fw;
```

```

And actually, while writing this post I can see in the console, that it gets triggered again ... minutes later. Something spooky is going in here.

Answer (score 0):

In case you run into the same 'situation':
Normally working in FireFox. At some point I had opened Chrome to use the debugger, and forgot all about it. THAT was the bugger continuously sending requests in the background ... sigh! Yes, web dev IS hard.

So check all possible incoming channels ; )